# How to get notifications to appear right after page loads? (Xamarin, LocalNotifications Plugin)

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I have a project that needs notifications about upcoming events to show when the user opens the main page, and I'm having problems with async and await (I think). I am using the LocalNotifications Nuget plugin, because that's the only one I was allowed to use for this project. I have some methods that are intended to check for and display notifications. I have tried loading them from my App file, My MainPage.Xaml.cs's OnAppearing method, and from my MainPageViewModel.cs, and the closest that I've gotten to something working is with a combination of creating the Notifications as a class, adding them from the ViewModel and displaying them in the OnAppearing Method of the code behind. The code works right up until the if statement's body in the OnAppearing Method tries to execute and then it just stops and continues on with displaying the main page, but never showing the notifications. I am really new to using asynchronous programming, as well as Xamarin, so I'm pretty confused. This is my relevant code.

```
//Code starts in MainPageViewModel.cs

public MainPageViewModel()
{
     Task.Run(async() => await CheckNotifications());
}


private async Task CheckNotifications()
{
     await DatabaseService.Init();
     var eventList = await DatabaseService.db.Table<Event>().ToListAsync();
           
     if (eventList.Count > 0)
     {
          foreach (Event event in eventList)
          {
               if (event.NotifyStartDate && (event.StartDate.Date == DateTime.Today))
               {
                    Notifications notification = new Notifications
                    {
                         Name = $"{event.Name}",
                         NotifyDate = event.StartDate,
                         Occurrence = "Starting"
                    };
                    await DatabaseService.AddNotification(notification);
               }
               if (event.NotifyEndDate && (event.EndDate.Date == DateTime.Today))
               {
                    Notifications notification = new Notifications
                    {
                         Name = $"{event.Name}",
                         NotifyDate = event.EndDate,
                         Occurrence = "Ending"
                    };
                    await DatabaseService.AddNotification(notification);
               }
          }
     } 
}
```

This all seems to work fine, it creates a Notification with the event that starts today and adds it to the Notifications Table in the database. Next it moves to my **MainPage Code Behind's OnAppearing** method--> which is an async void method and I can't figure out any other way to do this, because I get an error that "MainPage.OnAppearing() return type must be void" if I try to make it a Task.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
     //List fills fine here and holds my Test Event starting today information with a count of 1
     var notifications = await DatabaseService.db.Table<Notifications>().ToListAsync();
     
     if (notifications.Count > 0)
     {
          foreach(Notifications notification in notifications)
          {
               CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Reminder", $"Event {notification.Name} is {notification.Occurrence} Today" +
                        $"on {notification.NotifyDate}"); 
//code stops at this line and continues the rest of the program without executing notification
          }
     }
     base.OnAppearing();
}
```

My Init, FillSampleData, and AddNotifications methods in the database are all async tasks, and they all await other methods, but the problem seems to occur at OnAppearing. To add to that I am Navigating to the Main Page from App.Xaml.cs Synchrounously, because when I tried to make it an asynchronous method it got ignored there.

```
public App()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

Everywhere else in my app the navigation awaits. I don't know if I'm just doing the notifications all wrong, if I'm just doing Asynchronous programming all wrong, or a little bit of both. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Which specific plug-in are you using?  CrossLocalNotifications Has not been updated in 4 years

Comment: I don't know anything about CrossLocalNotifications, but async/await code looks good. [`override async void OnAppearing` is the correct signature.] If you wrap `foreach(Notifications ...){ ...}` in a `try ... catch (Exception ex){}`, does it catch any exception?  As a test, If you move that code into a button's click handler, thus allowing the page to appear first, then click the button, does it work when press button?

Comment: I am using Xam.Plugin.Notifier edSnider/JamesMontemagno. This is super old, and unfortunately the only notification plugin I was allowed to use. The API Usage says
Call CrossLocalNotifications.Current from any project or PCL to gain access to APIs. This is the link I was given if anyone wants to look at it. https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. It seems to actually work by just adding the try catch block. It may have worked before. I just wanted my notifications to appear at the top of my screen and they appear with the rest of my notifications. It also only sends one notification, no matter how many notifications there are. But that is a different problem. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to move the code about showing notifications to some other places such as the button clicked event to check if the notifications will show or not? In addition, what kind of device you chose to test on?